# increment is not happening in for loop in c

Tags: c, for-loop

I had written a program in C in which the population of a town increases by 10% each year, but the variable `pop` is not incrementing in the `for` loop.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { // B main
    int pop = 100000, year, popatend;
    printf("\nyear\t\t\tpopulation\n\n");
    for (year = 1; year <= 10; year++) { // B loop
        popatend = pop * (10 / 100);
        pop = pop + popatend;

        printf("%d\t\t\t %d\n", year, pop);
    } // B loop
} // B main
```

And this is the output:

```
year            population

   1             100000
   2             100000
   3             100000
   4             100000
   5             100000
   6             100000
   7             100000
   8             100000
   9             100000
  10             100000
```

I made this program in Eclipse, in ubuntu mate.

Comment: `popatend` is an integer and you're trying to mutiply it by a number that is less than one. What would be the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10/100 is integer division, so 0.

Comment: thanks i accept answer in 12 minutes cause i cant do it right now.

Answer (score 4):

You have integer division, `10/100` will be truncated to zero. Use `10.0 / 100.0` (or plain `0.1`) instead.

Answer (score 3):

When you do integer division:

```
  popatend=pop*(10/100);
```

`popatend` will have a value of `0`, since `(10/100)` will evaluate to `0`.

So when you add it to `pop`, the value of `pop` will not change.

I believe this could be fixed by changing it to

```
  popatend=pop*(10f/100f);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using integer division when you do `10/100`, so rather than returning `0.1`, it's actually truncating to `0`. Thus, you're setting `popatend` to zero every loop (`popatend = pop * 0`), and effectively adding zero to `pop` every time.

To fix this, you could either cast or change the types of`pop` and `popatend`, or use `10f/100f`.

Answer (score -2):

and you have `(year = 1; year <= 10; year++)`, which `year` here never serve as a factor in the calculation, that's why.

Comment: This is incorrect - the calculation is applied every iteration of the loop, year is the loop counter. It doesn't need to be in the calculation at all.

Comment: Please check well, the variable 'year' was well not at all used anywhere in ther calculation of new value, that's why he doesn't see any 'increment'

Comment: Matt is right - the way he structured the loop, it wasn't meant to be used in the calculation. If he changes it from integer division, it should work as desired, without the need to use `year`